# Practical applications of Rank 2 polymorphism?

Tags: haskell, polymorphism

I'm covering polymorphism and I'm trying to see the practical uses of such a feature.

My basic understanding of Rank 2 is:

```
type MyType = ∀ a. a -> a

subFunction :: a -> a
subFunction el = el

mainFunction :: MyType -> Int
mainFunction func = func 3
```

I understand that this is allowing the user to use a polymorphic function (subFunction) inside mainFunction and strictly specify it's output (Int). This seems very similar to GADT's:

```
data Example a where
 ExampleInt :: Int -> Example Int
 ExampleBool :: Bool -> Example Bool
```

1) Given the above, is my understanding of Rank 2 polymorphism correct?

2) What are the general situations where Rank 2 polymorphism can be used, as opposed to GADT's, for example?

Comment: Real world example: [`runST :: (forall s. ST s a) -> a`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Monad-ST.html#v:runST) keeps two separate `ST` computations from having the same `s`. This prevents you from leaking [`STRef`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-STRef.html#t:STRef)s outside the `ST` monad.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why rank-2 functions seem similar to GADTs to you. Can you clarify what you mean by that?

Comment: @DanielWagner At least existential types can be expressed with GADTs (e.g `data Ext where Ext :: a -> Ext`). Probably also other constructs that could be expressed with Rank 2 Types?

Comment: One can encode the equality between two types (as in the 'canonical' GADT - `data (:~:) a b where Refl :: a :~: a`) using rank 2 types - `newtype (:~:) a b = Refl (forall p . p a -> p b)` - and a similar such encoding is used in [`lens`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.1/docs/Control-Lens-Equality.html).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you pass a polymorphic function as and argument to a Rank2-polymorphic function, you're essentially passing not just one function but a whole *family* of functions – for all possible types that fulfill the constraints.

Typically, those forall quantifiers come with a class constraint. For example, I might wish to do number arithmetic with two different types simultaneously (for comparing precision or whatever).

```
data FloatCompare = FloatCompare {
     singlePrecision :: Float
   , doublePrecision :: Double
   }
```

Now I might want to modify those numbers through some maths operation. Something like

```
modifyFloat :: (Num -> Num) -> FloatCompare -> FloatCompare
```

But `Num` is not a type, only a type class. I could of course pass a function that would modify any *particular* number type, but I couldn't use that to modify *both* a `Float` and a `Double` value, at least not without some ugly (and possibly lossy) converting back and forth.

Solution: Rank-2 polymorphism!

```
modifyFloat :: (∀ n . Num n => n -> n) -> FloatCompare -> FloatCompare
mofidyFloat f (FloatCompare single double)
    = FloatCompare (f single) (f double)
```

The best single example of how this is useful in practice are probably [lenses](http://lens.github.io/tutorial.html). A lens is a “smart accessor function” to a field in some larger data structure. It allows you to access fields, update them, gather results... while at the same time composing in a very simple way. How it works: Rank2-polymorphism; every lens is polymorphic, with the different instantiations corresponding to the “getter” / “setter” aspects, respectively.

Comment: This is a great answer, the additional introduction to lenses is much appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

The go-to example of an application of rank-2 types is `runST` as Benjamin Hodgson mentioned in the comments.  This is a rather good example and there are a variety of examples using the same trick. For example, [branding](http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/eliminating-array-bound-check.lhs) to maintain abstract data type invariants across multiple types, avoiding confusion of differentials in [ad](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ad-4.3.2.1/docs/Numeric-AD.html), a [region-based version of ST](http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/regions.html#light-weight).

But I'd actually like to talk about how Haskell programmers are implicitly using rank-2 types all the time.  Every type class whose methods have universally quantified types desugars to a dictionary with a field with a rank-2 type.  In practice, this is virtually always a higher-kinded type class<sup>*</sup> like `Functor` or `Monad`. I'll use a simplified version of [`Alternative`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#g:2) as an example.  The class declaration is:

```
class Alternative f where
    empty :: f a
    (<|>) :: f a -> f a -> f a
```

The dictionary representing this class would be:

```
data AlternativeDict f = AlternativeDict {
    empty :: forall a. f a,
    (<|>) :: forall a. f a -> f a -> f a }
```

Sometimes such an encoding is nice as it allows one to use different "instances" for the same type, perhaps only locally.  For example, `Maybe` has two obvious instances of `Alternative` depending on whether `Just a <|> Just b` is `Just a` or `Just b`. Languages without type classes, such as Scala, do indeed [use this encoding](https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/snapshots/archive/org/scalaz/scalaz_2.12/7.3.0-SNAPSHOT/scalaz_2.12-7.3.0-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar/!/scalaz/PlusEmpty.html).

To connect to leftaroundabout's reference to [lenses](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens), you can view the hierarchy there as a hierarchy of type classes and the lens combinators as simply tools for explicitly building the relevant type class dictionaries.  Of course, the reason it isn't *actually* a hierarchy of type classes is that we usually will have multiple "instances" for the same type.  E.g. `_head` and `_head . _tail` are [both](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.1/docs/Control-Lens-Cons.html#v:_head) "instances" of `Traversal' s a`.

<sup>*</sup> A higher-kinded type class doesn't necessarily lead to  this, and it can happen for a type class of kind `*`. For example:

```
-- Higher-kinded but doesn't require universal quantification.
class Sum c where
    sum :: c Int -> Int

-- Not higher-kinded but does require universal quantification.
class Length l where
    length :: [a] -> l
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using modules in Haskell, you are already using Rank-2 types. Theoretically speaking, modules are records with rank-2 type properties.

For example, the `Foo` module below in Haskell ...

```
module Foo(id) where
id :: forall a. a -> a
id x = x
```

```
import qualified Foo
main = do
  putStrLn (Foo.id "hello")
  return ()
```

... can actually be thought as a record as follows:

```
type FooType = FooType {
  id :: forall a. a -> a
}
Foo :: FooType
Foo = Foo {
  id = \x -> x
}
```

P/S (unrelated this question): from a language design perspective, if you are going to support module system, then you might as well support higher-rank types (i.e. allow arbitrary quantification of type variables on any level) to reduce duplication of efforts (i.e. type checking a module should be almost the same as type checking a record with higher rank types).